# Why are people providing answers in comments?

Tags: discussion, comment, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)

I've noticed that there are many examples of people providing partial answers or pointers in the comments to a question instead of attempting to answer the question. I find this practice confusing and detrimental to the organization of the site. Wouldn't the community prefer to have comments that answer parts of the question posted as proper answers instead. They could then be voted up or down and their contribution would be easier to assess.

My suggestion is to emphasize this more within the community and the FAQs and to let the comments be just that: comments *about* a question or answer, not an attempt at answering the original question. It should be acceptable to give brief or partial answers only.

Another suggestion is to add a verification step when posting comments to the *original* question where the purpose of comments is made clear to the commenter.

Comment: As this is a discussion I think any only comments are appropirate responses to this.  I gave a +1 because this bothered me too.  But I have done it too because one time I gave a partial answer and someone downvoted me saying it was not an answer. so to avoid the silly downvotes I started putting them in comments where people don't downvote.

Comment: @cardinal What does this comment of yours mean?

Comment: If you mean that might comment is an answer to the title I would say that it is a partial answer explaining why I put aprtial answers in comments.  I didn't make this comment an answer because it was partialand I don't consider titles to be questions.  I would asnwer it if it was mentioned in the authors original discussion.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: It is an automatically generated comment when one votes to close a question as a duplicate.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion on the duplicate. FYI, nothing has changed regarding mod capabilities for comment->answer conversion. (Sorry, but the automatically generated comment pointing to the duplicate referred above will disappear when this question is closed.)